# Updating form with PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql

So I got this form where I want to be able to edit the data thats coming from the database.

I am able to readout the data into form

[image]

Editing/Updating seems not to work.

Part of my HTML code:

```
       <form id="formAddChallenges" class="FrmChal" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="row">
              <!-- Left Column -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value="<?php echo $hiddenID ?>" />
                  <label class="control-label">Challenge</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Challenge name" name="challenge" required="" value="<?php echo $challenge ?>" />
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                  <textarea required="" class="form-control" rows="5" name="description"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description)?></textarea>
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Points</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How many points is this challenge worth?" name="points" required="" value="<?php echo $points ?>" />
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="selectType" >
                    <option disabled selected><?php echo $typeId?></option>
                    <!-- <option  selected></option> -->
                    <option value="1">Photo</option>
                    <option value="2">Geolocation</option>
                    <option value="3">Quiz</option>
                    <option value="4">Time</option>
                    <option value="5">Puzzle</option>
                    <option value="6">Vote</option>
                    <option value="7">Tracking/Checkpoints</option>
                    <option value="8">Augmented Reality</option>
                  </select>
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Status</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="selectStatus">
                    <option disabled selected><?php echo $status?></option>
                    <option value="1">Active</option>
                    <option value="2">Finished</option>
                  </select>
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-autoclose" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="startdate" value="<?php echo $startD ?>" />
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">End Date</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-autoclose2" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" name="enddate" value="<?php echo $endD ?>" />
                </div>  
                <!-- Right Column -->
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <label class="control-label">Upload a picture</label>
                  <br>
                  <?php echo $picture ?>
                  <br><br><br><br>
                  <input type="file" id="input-file-now" class="dropify" name="uploadPicture" /> 
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Category</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="selectCategory">
                    <option disabled selected><?php echo $categoryId?></option>
                    <option value="1">Food &amp; Drink</option>
                    <option value="2">Creative</option>
                    <option value="3">Sport</option>
                    <option value="4">Games</option>
                    <option value="5">Youtube</option>
                    <option value="6">Fashion</option>
                    <option value="7">Animals</option>
                    <option value="8">Movie &amp; Tv</option>
                    <option value="9">General</option>
                    <option value="10">Adventure</option>
                    <option value="11">Lifestyle</option>
                    <option value="12">Travel</option>
                    <option value="13">Music</option>
                    <option value="14">Events</option>
                  </select>
                  <br>
                  <label class="control-label">Difficulty</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="selectDifficulty">
                     <option disabled selected><?php echo $difficutlyId?></option>
                    <option value="1">Easy</option>
                    <option value="2">Normal</option>
                    <option value="3">Hard</option>
                    <option value="4">Extreme</option>
                  </select>
                  <!-- <div class="fillEmptSpace"></div> -->
                </div>  
              </div><!-- end row -->
              <br>
              <button type="submit" id="btnEditChallenge" class="btn btn-danger" name="editChallenge">Edit Challenge</button>
            </form>
```

Part of my php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'config.php';//db connection

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

$id = $_GET['challenge_id'];
//select data from db and place it in input field
$query_string = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Challenges 
        INNER JOIN 
          tbl_Type ON tbl_Challenges.type_id=tbl_Type.type_id
        INNER JOIN 
          tbl_Status ON tbl_Challenges.status_id=tbl_Status.status_id
        INNER JOIN 
          tbl_Category ON tbl_Challenges.category_id=tbl_Category.category_id
        INNER JOIN 
          tbl_Difficulty ON tbl_Challenges.difficulty_id=tbl_Difficulty.difficulty_id  
        WHERE challenge_id = '$id'";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $query_string);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $hiddenID = $row['challenge_id'];
  $challenge = $row['challenge'];
  $description = $row['description'];
  $points = $row["points"];
  $picture = '<img src="'.$row['picture'].'" width="250" heigth="186" />';
  //$picture = $row['picture'];
  $categoryId = $row['category'];
  $typeId = $row['type'];
  $difficutlyId = $row['difficulty'];
  $status = $row['status'];
  $startD = $row['start_date'];
  $endD = $row['end_date'];
}

//edit/update data to db
if(isset($_POST['editChallenge'])){
  $challengeUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['challenge']);
  $challengeID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['hiddenId']);
  $descriptionUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['description']);
  $pointsUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['points']);
  $categoryUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['selectCategory']);
  $typeUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['selectType']);
  $difficultyUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['selectDifficulty']);
  $statusUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['selectStatus']);
  $startDateUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['startdate']);
  $endDateUpdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['enddate']);
  $qry =  "UPDATE tbl_Challenges SET 
            category = '$challengeUpdate',
            description = '$descriptionUpdate ',
            points = '$pointsUpdate',
            category_id = '$categoryUpdate',
            type_id = '$typeUpdate',
            difficutly_id = '$difficultyUpdate',
            status_id = '$statusUpdate',
            start_date = '$startDateUpdate',
            end_date = '$endDateUpdate'
            WHERE challenge_id = '$challengeID
          ";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);
  echo $qry;
}

if($result){
  header("Location: challenges.php"); 
}

?>
```

When I hit the save button nothing gets saved. The output of the echo $qry looks like this:

[image: the]

Comment: `WHERE challenge_id = '$challengeID` is missing a single quote at the end.

Comment: and not checking for errors on the query, didn't help you.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.